# Issue with psuedo mode configuration of Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to do pseudo mode configuration of **Hadoop 2.0.4** version. Script start-dfs.sh works fine. However, **start-mapred.sh** fails to start the jobtracker and tasktracker. Below is the error I am getting. Seeing at error it looks like it is not able to pick the jar file. Please let me know if you have any idea of this issue. Thanks.

```
FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobACLsManager.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf;)V
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.<init>(JobTracker.java:2182)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.<init>(JobTracker.java:1895)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.<init>(JobTracker.java:1889)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.startTracker(JobTracker.java:311)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.startTracker(JobTracker.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.startTracker(JobTracker.java:297)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.main(JobTracker.java:4820)
```

Comment: have you set all the environment variables? check this link http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

Comment: No..I have not set any of the Yarn related environment variable. Is it compulsory to run Yarn?

Comment: well i am not sure. you can try setting $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME and $HADOOP_YARN_HOME

Comment: there is not init method for JobACLsManager. It looks strange. http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.serialization-all/2.0.4/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobACLsManager.java?av=f

Comment: Yes. You're right. I too checked the file. I'll try setting up the variables you mentioned and will let you know the result. Thanks.

Comment: Answer this question with whatever you have done to make it work so that it will be useful for others :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was using incorrect jars. So, first I replaced those. Then, I just created a new directory with hadoop conf files. Formatted the namenode. Finally it worked. :)